# Why I have a different behavior of `Path(os.getcwd())` in a cronjob and direct cmd call?

Tags: linux, cron, python

I try to write some Data in a CSV file by a Python3 script.
If I run this direct in the CMD it works very well, but if i run it by cron ( setted up by `crontab -e`) it does not work.

Now I've found out that I need the direct path (hardcoded  in my code as a constant string) to this file.

But my first approach was confusing me. I run the command `Path(os.getcwd()).joinpath('Data/test.csv')` and get the correct path `/home/pi/Documents/Project/Data/test.csv`. But as i run it by a cron, the path was `/home/pi/Data/test.csv`.

The project is located at `/home/pi/Documents/Project/`. Why `Path(os.getcwd()).joinpath('Data/test.csv')` returns an other path, than a direct call by cmd?

What could i change that i've the same behavior in a cron and in a comandline call of my scirpt?

*EDIT*

This is my crontab entry:
`00 9,15 * * * python3 /home/pi/Documents/Projects/temperatureCheck/temperatureCheck.py`

Comment: Your command line runs in /home/pi/Documents/Project. Cron runs in your home directory. How would crontab know which current directory you might change to in your terminal session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix your crontab command with:

```
cd /home/pi/Documents/Project && ...
```